# QueryException: ResultTransformer is not allowed for 'select new' queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have the following SpringData Repository Query:

```
    @Query("SELECT new com.mypackage.MobileCaseList(c.ident, concat(c.subtype, ' - ', c.contactName), c.type, coalesce(c.updateTimestamp,c.insertTimestamp) )" +  
            "FROM MobileCase c WHERE c.mobileUser.ident = ?1 AND c.origin = 'SOURCE' ORDER BY c.appointmentFrom NULLS LAST") 
    List<MobileCaseList> findCasesForUser(String userIdent);
```

And following runtime code:

```
    List<MobileCaseList> result = caseRepo.findCasesForUser(userIdent);
```

This worked fine until now - no idea what causes the exception now. On my PC (localhost) it still works!? But on the Ubuntu server the query execution fails with following error:

```
2016-02-17 12:56:49.696 ERROR 13397 --- [http-nio-9090-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: ResultTransformer is not allowed for 'select new' queries.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: ResultTransformer is not allowed for 'select new' queries.] with root cause

org.hibernate.QueryException: ResultTransformer is not allowed for 'select new' queries.
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.checkQuery(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.0.M1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.0.M1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.0.M1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.0.M1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.M1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.M1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.0.M1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.10.0.M1.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:na
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy144.findCasesForUser(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

**Any ideas, suggestions...?**

Comment: I have the same problem after updating spring-data-jpa to the latest version...

Comment: There is an issue about this. https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-938

Comment: Did you have a look at the issue? Maybe you used different versions of spring data?

Comment: Bad news I think... @leonardoborges seems to have found the reason why... (upvoted)

Answer (score 0):

As @leonardoborges wrote, this issue [was described as bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-938), and should be fixed since version 1.10.3. There is nothing more to add here about the problem.

Comment: @community is the bug fixed now? I am still facing this issue

Comment: can anybody help me with this issue, As I am still facing the same thing as given above?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a native query with `nativequery=true`